# Pandas DF scatter-plot: adding color removes x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm using Python with Pandas (in Jupyter Notebook), and following [this tutorial](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/scatter-plot-from-pandas-dataframe/), I plot my data-frame using pandas.DataFrame.plot. I have an issue, similar to the tutorial, that when I add color to the plot, the x-axis no longer has values or a title.

df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height")

[image: No color: df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height")]

df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height", c="Team Color")

[image: Color: df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height", c="Team Color")]

Is there a simple way to keep the x-axis title and values in a colored plot?

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
# dataframe of height and weight football players
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Height': [167, 175, 170, 186, 190, 188, 158, 169, 183, 180],
    'Weight': [65, 70, 72, 80, 86, 94, 50, 58, 78, 85],
    'Team': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']
})
ax = df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height")
df['Team Color'] = df['Team'].map({'A': 'Red', 'B': 'Blue'})
ax = df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height", c="Team Color")
```

## Update:

Folowing @TC Arlen's suggestion, I updated Pandas from v1.0.5 to 1.3.1. My Python version is 3.8.3. The update fixed the issue for this example, but surprisingly the issue still exists for variations of the code. For example, the code from [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],

                   [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],

                  columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])

ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',

                      y='width',

                      c='species',

                      colormap='viridis')
```

The site shows the plot:
[image: Pandas' plot]

but when I run this code, I get, again, no x-axis values or title:

[image]

so my problem remains.

Comment: a minimal working example of oyur code would be nice (not a link to another site)

Comment: @raphael The problem is identical to the tutorial. The code is in the link.

Comment: well, yes but if that site is gone nobody will know what the actual question was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
ax = df.plot.scatter(x="Weight", y="Height", c="Team Color")
ax.set_xlabel('Weight')
```

**EDIT**: It looks like something weird is going on with the pandas scatter plot function, with different versions giving different problems. So sticking to pure `pyplot` would give this for the iris dataset example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
                   [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],
                  columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])

plt.scatter(x=df['length'], y=df['width'], c=df['species'], cmap='viridis')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Species')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlabel('length')
ax.set_ylabel('width')
```

Comment: This does not seem to change the plot.

Comment: Shoot, that works on my system. Maybe try updating your pandas version? Mine is version `1.3.1`. What is yours?

Comment: My version was 1.0.5. After updating to 1.3.1 the problem was solved, even without adding your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: strangely the problem remains...I edited the post.

Comment: @RdBasha Weird, but I got the same thing you did. I edited my post to include the correct plot for a pure pyplot implementation. Does this work for you?